# Dual monitor setup in Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela

Tags: linux-mint, x11, xorg, multi-monitor, asus

OK so I have been going at this problem hammer and tong for 6 days now (and over two weeks in a previous attempt).

My problem is setting up Linux Mint with an external monitor plugged into my laptop.

I have tried possibly every suggestion I could find online without success. And now I am ready to break my laptop for trying and failing!

---

**My System and Hardware**

- Laptop: Asus X5DC
- `lspci | grep -i vga` output: `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller:
  Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter
  (rev 10)`
- External monitor: ViewSonic VX912
- `xrandr` output: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
  Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
  default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
  1024x768       76.0* 
  1504x1200_60.00 (0x1ab)  151.4MHz
      h: width  1504 start 1608 end 1768 total 2032 skew    0 clock   74.5KHz
      v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1242           clock   60.0Hz`
- `sudo lshw -C video` output: `*-display UNCLAIMED
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter
     vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
     version: 10
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 66MHz
     capabilities: pm agp agp-3.0 vga_controller cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe9e0000-fe9fffff ioport:dc00(size=128)`

---

**What I have tried already**

- Editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf many times and sometimes X wouldn't start so I had to undo my changes from tty terminal and restart. Here is my current xorg.conf:

  ```
  Section "ServerLayout"
      Identifier     "X.org Configured"
      Screen         "Screen0" LeftOf "Screen1"
  EndSection

  Section "Monitor"
      Identifier   "Configured Monitor"
      VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
      ModelName    "Monitor Model"
      HorizSync 28-72
      VertRefresh 43-60
  EndSection

  Section "Device"
      Identifier  "Card0"
      Driver      "sis"
      BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
  EndSection

  Section "Screen"
      Identifier "Screen0"
      Device     "Card0"
      Monitor    "Monitor0"
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     1
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     4
          Modes      "900x675" "1024x768" "1280x960" "1400x1050"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     8
          Modes      "900x675" "1024x768" "1280x960" "1400x1050"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     15
          Modes      "900x675" "1024x768" "1280x960" "1400x1050"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     16
          Modes      "900x675" "1024x768" "1280x960" "1400x1050"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     24
          Modes      "900x675" "1024x768" "1280x960" "1400x1050"
      EndSubSection
  EndSection

  Section "Screen"
      Identifier "Screen1"
      Device     "Card0"
      Monitor    "Monitor0"
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     1
          Modes      "1280x1024" "1500x1200" "1640x1312"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     4
          Modes      "1280x1024" "1500x1200" "1640x1312"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     8
          Modes      "1280x1024" "1500x1200" "1640x1312"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     15
          Modes      "1280x1024" "1500x1200" "1640x1312"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     16
          Modes      "1280x1024" "1500x1200" "1640x1312"
      EndSubSection
      SubSection "Display"
          Viewport   0 0
          Depth     24
          Modes      "1280x1024" "1500x1200" "1640x1312"
      EndSubSection
  EndSection
  ```

  `
- I have added the following .conf files to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d:

  - 41-built-in-monitor.conf which contains:

    ```
        Section "Monitor"
            Identifier   "Monitor0"
            VendorName   "Built in Monitor"
            ModelName    "Model Unknown"
            HorizSync       28.0 - 70.0
            VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
        EndSection
    ```
  - 42-second-vga-monitor.conf which contains:

    ```
        Section "Monitor"
            Identifier   "Monitor1"
            VendorName   "ViewSonic"
            ModelName    "VX912"
            Option       "RightOf"  "Monitor0"
            HorizSync       28.0 - 70.0
            VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
        Endsection
    ```
  - 50-video.conf which contains:

    ```
        Section "Device"
            Identifier "Device2"
            Option  "Monitor-Built-In" "Monitor0"
            Option  "Monitor-VGA"      "Monitor1"
            Driver "sis"
        EndSection
    ```
- `sudo update-pciids`
- `gtf 1500 1200 60 -x`
  output: `# 1504x1200 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 74.52 kHz; pclk: 151.42 MHz
  Modeline "1504x1200_60.00"  151.42  1504 1608 1768 2032  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync`
- `xrandr --newmode  "1504x1200_60.00"  151.42  1504 1608 1768 2032 1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync` output: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
  X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19`
- `xrandr --addmode VGA1 1504x1200_60.00` output: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
  xrandr: cannot find output "VGA1"`
- `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1504x1200_60.00` output: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
  warning: output VGA1 not found; ignoring`

And many more suggestions I found, in fact I'e tried that many things I could not list them here even if I could remember!

---

Mate Monitor Preferences does not recognize external monitor (obviously).

Arandr acts as though I only have the 'default' monitor.

My system is displaying on both screens but **not** seperately, as in its the same on both monitors, so the monitor works and the VGA adapter works and the graphics card can output to both, just not as a proper dual monitor setup.

If anyone knows what exactly is ~/.config/monitors.xml for?